# Duda concepto programación orientada a objetos

Tags: c#

Estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programación orientada a objetos, leo y leo ejemplos pero no termino de entender el concepto o la filosofía de esta forma de programación.

Vengo del mundo de la programación industrial (robótica, plc industrial etc...) Programación estructurada y orientada a procesos, la cual tiene sus declaraciones de variables y yo trabajo con éstas desde cualquier punto del programa con cualquiera de estas variables, digamos que son accesos globales...

Ahora viene el caso de la POO... Para empezar, en C# directamente tengo que tener una clase, llamemosle X  en la cual voy creando procedimientos y en uno de estos instancio una clase Y.

Como quiero tener ordenado mi programa (o estructurado), hago otras clases diferentes para tratar otras partes de mi programa.

El problema que tengo normalente es el siguiente:

Necesito acceder a propiedades o metodos del objeto que instancie de la clase Y en otra clase y zasca! No tengo permisos porque esta instanciada en otra clase... ¿Que demonios? No acabo de entender el por qué... Si necesito acceso que hago? Patron singleton... ¿Pero siempre? No veo los beneficios que aporta la POO...

---

no, no me refiero a eso...
Me explico;

```
    namespace Espacio1
    {
        public partial class Principal : Form
        {
            public Principal()
            {
            int var1 = 100;
            }
        }
    }

    namespace Espacio2
    {
       public partial class CUALESMIIP : Form
        {
            public prueba()
            {
                *******************
            }
```

¿Como accedo al valor de var1 desde el procedimiento prueba()?

---

No me refiero a crear una propiedad y llamarla, mas bien el ejemplo es el siguiente;

```
    namespace ConsoleApp3
    {
         class Program
         {
             static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ConsoleApp3.Class1.variable);
            }
         }
    }

    namespace ConsoleApp3
   {
        class Class1
        {
            public int variable = 100;
        }
    }
```

Lo que necesito es consultar el valor de "variable", pero ese mismo valor, no instanciar la clase y utilizarla en otra con otro valor... Busco leer un valor concreto, es decir, si yo en un momento dado no necesito utilizar una clase como tal... (propiedades, metodos etc... ¿Necesito crear el codigo en una clase como tal? ¿Aqui no hay un procedimiento tal cual? que no este dentro de una clase... :D

Comment: bienvenido hermano, me alegra que estés iniciando a programar, esto te será de mucha utilidad: https://mva.microsoft.com/ aquí hay un curso excelente de C# para principantes muy completo. Para que tu pregunta sea entendible y que la comunidad pueda ayudarte a resolverla, necesitas editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que estás intentado hacer. Saludos :D

Comment: Buenas tardes, te entiendo completamente llevo 4 años desarrollando con C# y 3 años usando POO y si te soy complentamente honesto desconocia el valor de la programacion orientada a objetos te recomiendo leer el libro patrones de diseño https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527730-01.aspx lee los patrones adapter y facade mis favoritos, para darte un resumen el uso de clases abstractas, interfaces, Task es lo que le va a dar mas sabor al uso del POO, despues que lo uses creeme veras todo desde otro angulo

Comment: Te recomiendo este post de POO https://thenullpointerexceptionx.blogspot.com/2019/07/programacion-orientada-objetos.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a ser claro, no voy a usar nombres complicados ni te voy a indicar tutoriales, si no que te voy a explicar tu problema con claridad.

Una clase no es mas que una parte de tu programa encapsulada.

Así como en programación procedural, tenias funciones, y armabas librerías de funciones, una clase no es mas que una librería de funciones con sus propias variables. Entonces lo que hace tu programa es crear pequeñas librerías, que tienen sus funciones y sus propias variables, muchas veces.

Lo vemos mejor con un pequeño ejemplo.

Procedural:

Quiero una lista de autos. Entonces tendríamos que tener un vector con las patentes.. y si quiero el color? bueno, tendríamos un vector que contiene otro vector dentro que tiene los datos de la patente y el color... y si quiero la presión de los neumáticos? tendría un vector que contiene un vector de autos que tiene patente, color, y un vector de neumáticos, que en cada posición tiene la presión.. ufff... imagínate si también quiero agregar el tipo de neumático (porque tengo cuatro diferentes!)

Y ni hablar de como usar esto.. imagínate tratar de recorrerlo...

Clases:

Quiero una lista de autos. Entonces tengo la clase auto. Esta clase tiene una variable patente. una variable color. un vector neumáticos con la presión de cada uno. Para usarlo, creas un vector que en cada posición tiene un auto (un elemento de la clase auto). y accedes directamente a sus propiedades (las variables que creaste a nivel de clase, que digamos son globales a la clase, se llaman propiedades). Ya que estamos, en las clases las funciones se llaman métodos.

Y  si quiero agregar el tipo de neumático?? entonces podría tener una clases neumático, y que mi clase auto, en el vector de neumáticos, tenga una instancia (o sea, una pequeña "librería" autocontenida de métodos y variables), para cada neumático. es mas.. imagínate que si quisiera agregar el color del neumático (si, tengo problemas y quiero mis neumáticos de varios colores), en objetos me alcanza con agregar una propiedad a la clase neumáticos con el color.. Ahora imaginatelo procedural...

Ahora, mas alla de estos beneficios, estas obligado a usar clases?

Por supuesto que no. tu programa podría ser una sola clase que tenga todo adentro. Y eso no varia nada. podrías trabajar en un entorno POO con una sola clase y manejarla totalmente procedural.

Revisando tu ejemplo, tu principal problema es el SCOPE. Las variables adentro de los métodos, son lo mismo que las variables dentro de las funciones procedurales. Mueren ahí. para ver propiedades, debes crearlas a nivel de clase, fuera de todo procedimiento de la clase, como si fueran globales.

Y si, puedes usar clases estáticas (que no necesitan ser creadas antes de ser usadas) y montones de trucos mas. Pero ya todo eso depende de para que tipo de sistema estés trabajando.

**Editado:**

Segun lo que agregaste a tu pregunta, y tal vez no me explique bien, pero no necesitas otra clase para guardar el valor de una variable. Puede estar en tu misma clase donde la buscas.

en tu caso, variable podria estar en la class program

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
    {
         class Program
         {

             public int variable = 100;

             static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ConsoleApp3.Class1.variable);
            }
         }
    }
```

Y si quisieras el valor que esta dentro de una clase? Bueno, ahí tenemos montones de formas de hacerlo, pero para simplificarte la vida, porque no tienes ese valor a mano, en la propia clase que lo necesita.

Piensa que en el ejemplo del auto, cada vez que creamos un auto, este se crea sin datos. Por lo general, las clases no tienen datos propios (se crean vacías) y uno tiene que completarlas. (si, podrías tener una clase con montones de cadenas de caracteres estáticas; y se hace; pero esto es solo una idea para un primerizo).

Para que los valores estén en otra clase y puedas acceder a ellos sin "crear" la clase, por ejemplo, se usan clases que se llaman estáticas. Estas son como "librerías" ya cargadas, que mantienen siempre los valores que contienen, aunque vos no las instancies. Técnicamente están instanciadas ya al cargar el programa en "algún lado" que no nos interesa, pero que permite que las usemos.

Comment: Hermano, hay una edición a la pregunta que va dirigida hacia tu persona :D

Answer (score 2):

No tienes permisos?  a qué te refieres exactamente?

A menos que estés declarando tus variables como private o en casos especiales protected, tienes accesos a los metodos y atributos a través de un objeto

No conozco C# pero daré un ejemplo general de POO orientado un poco a java

```
public class X {
   private int atributo1;
   public int atributo2;

   public void funcion1() {
   }
   private void funcion2() {
   }

}
```

Si tu creas un nuevo objeto de esta clase `x = new X();` tendrás acceso al atributo 2 dado que es público y a la función 1, de los atributos 1 y funciones 2 no tienes acceso desde el objeto dado que es privado, solo dentro de la clase, en algunos lenguajes existe también protected que te permite entrar siempre y cuando sea clase hija, (herencia), Te recomiendo buscar mucho de encapsulamiento, ya que es una de las partes fundamentales a mi parecer de POO

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de agregar `int` a los campos definidos en tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Me gustaría darte una buena respuesta, pero el problema es que no termino de entender cual es tu problema. El ejemplo de tu segunda edición se solucionaría convirtiendo tu `variable` en estática y de esa manera podrías acceder a `variable` de la siguiente manera:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Class1.variable);
        }
     }

     class Class1
     {
        public static int variable = 100;
     }
}
```

De todas maneras, lo mejor sería que pusieras algun ejemplo de la vida real, de tal manera que podamos aconsejarte la mejor manera de solucionarlo. Ahora mismo es un poco abstracta tu duda y no entiendo que problema es el que intentas solucionar.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> namespace ConsoleApp3
> {
>     class Program
>     {
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(ConsoleApp3.Class1.variable);
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> namespace ConsoleApp3
> {
>     class Class1
>     {
>         public int variable = 100;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Lo que necesito es consultar el valor de "variable", pero ese mismo valor, **no instanciar la clase** y utilizarla en otra con otro valor.

No puedes. El dato `variable` de tipo `int` perteneciente a la clase `Class1` del espacio de nombres `ConsoleApp3` es una [variable de instancia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_de_instancia), así pues no existe sin instancia:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Class1
    {
        public int variable = 100;
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // varias instancias de Class1 
            ConsoleApp3.Class1 c1, c2;

            c2.variable *= 5;

            Console.WriteLine(c1.variable); // Muestra 100 
            Console.WriteLine(c2.variable); // Muestra 500 
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que tú buscas es una [variable de clase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_de_clase), que en C# (y otros lenguajes parecidos) se consigue usando [el cualificador `static`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static):

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Class1
    {
        static public int variable = 100;
     // ^^^^^^
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // varias instancias de Class1 
            ConsoleApp3.Class1 c1, c2;

            c2.variable *= 5; // Error! Es variable de clase, no de instancia

            Console.WriteLine(ConsoleApp3.Class1.variable); // Muestra 100 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Seria de esta forma

var1 seria una propiedad, aunque hay mas formas de hacer esto.

```
namespace Espacio1
{
    public partial class Principal : Form
    {

        public int var1 {get; set;}

        public Principal()
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace Espacio2
{
   public partial class CUALESMIIP : Form
    {
        Principal _principal = new Principal ()
        public prueba()
        {
            _principal .var1 = 0;
        }
    }
```

## Editado

Entiendo mas a fondo tu pregunta, en tu lugar usaría el patrón singleton, en frameworks como el dos se implementaba usando una variable estatica algo asi

```
public static int var 1;
```

puedes llamarla desde otra clase tal como tu lo expusiste sin embargo existen mejores practicas para hacer singleton con framework recientes para evitar deadlocks podrias hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Class1
{
    // Variable estática para la instancia, se necesita utilizar una función lambda ya que el constructor es privado
    private static readonly Lazy<Class1> instance = new Lazy<Class1>(() => new Class1());
    // Constructor privado para evitar la instanciación directa
    private Class1()
    {
    }

    public int var1; 
    // Propiedad para acceder a la instancia
    public static Class1 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance.Value;
        }
    }
}
// Clase de prueba
public class Test
{
   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {     
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.Instance.var1);    
   }
}
```

Comment: Aunque esto pueda ser una respuesta correcta, sería ideal si pudieras indicar cómo el código de arriba soluciona el problema planteado en la pregunta.

Comment: listo espero sea de utilidad

Comment: Yo evitaría el singleton a mas no poder, y lo dejaría únicamente para casos donde realmente es necesario. Lo mejor es aprender a diseñar tus clases para que la OOP funcione, un singleton digamos que rompe un poco con lo que la OOP pretende.